# How can I do a quiz with radiobutton?

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement

[image]I have a small problem, I'm trying to create a math quiz in WPF Apllication, where numbers will randomly pop up, which will be calculated according to the chosen math operation.
Everything works as planned, but now I've gotten to prepare Radiobutton and I have no idea how to come up with it. I would like to do this so that the Radiobuttons would take turns which answer would be correct (so that it was still not the first correctly). I know the answer will have to be written as Radiobutton's content. But I don't know how to set the condition for checking the correctness of the result.

```
if (firstPoss.Content == result.Text)
 {
 }

if (secondPoss.Content == result.Text)
 {
 }

 if (thirdPoss.Content == result.Text)
 {
 }
```

this IF statement always passes

I will be happy for any advice or nudges in the right direction.

Comment: If the math question is `13 * 2` what would the values of the radiobuttons then be? random numbers where one is 26 (the right answer)? and are you struggling with that part - on how to fill the radiobuttons with one right answer and a couple random answers?

Comment: @sommmen it fills in by giving another math operation for random numbers it's not a problem, my problem is how do i check that the user has chosen the correct radiobutton (which i would always swap)

Comment: @sommmen idea: one could assign that the correct answer will always be the first radiobutton but I will randomly shuffle it with some function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm speculating a bit since I do not find your use-case to be clear (perhaps add a picture or visual description?). but i think this should be what you want;

There are a lot of good resources out there, so why don't you start with investigating how the radiobutton works in general?

e.g.
https://wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-radiobutton-control/

Now we see that the `IsChecked` property signifies that a certain control is checked - be it by the user or programmatically.

Thus we can check that property:

```cs
if(firstPoss.Content == Result.Text && firstPoss.IsChecked)
{
   // The result is the same as the 'firstPoss' radiobutton, and the button is checked.
   // Debug.WriteLine("User checked the right answer!");
}
// ... etc.
```

EDIT:

Would something like this work in checking whether the right answer radiobutton is checked?

```cs
var answerRadioButtons = new RadioButton[] { firstPoss, secondPoss, thirdPoss };
var correctAnswerButtonFound = false;
foreach(var answerButton in answerRadioButtons)
{
     if(answerButton.IsChecked)
     {
        // The user checked this particular button
        if(answerButton.Text == Result.Text)
        {
            // The user checked this button, and the result text is the same as the radio button text - this means we have the right button
            correctAnswerButtonFound = true;
        }
     }
}

if(correctAnswerButtonFound)
{
     // The user pressed the correct answer button
}
else
{
     // The user did not press the correct answer button
}
```

Comment: that the radiobutton must be `IsChecked` it was clear to me but if I list it for all options then the answer will always be recognized as correct

Comment: Post a picuture of what you're looking at and/or descibe what you want in mspaint or something - because you're not making much sense.

Comment: I don't know if it will help,I apologize for my explanation

Comment: Still a small question pops up my mistake `Compiler Error CS0230` : Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement.  In line: `foreach(answerButton in answerRadioButtons)`

Comment: I think it should be `foreach(var answerButton in answerRadioButtons)` I forgot to specify the type (`var`) for the index variable.